# Problema con funcion def para una lista vacia usando random.randint

Tags: python

Hasta ahi todo bien, escribi esto:

```
import random

def numerosazar(n):
    random_numeros=[]
    for i in range(n):
        random_numeros.append(random.randint(1000,10000))
    return random_numeros

azar=numerosazar(random.randint(10,100))
print("Los numeros de la lista son: ",azar, "\n")
```

El problema es que me piden ademas que dentro de esa misma funcion (def) la cantidad de elementos tambien tiene que ser un numero al azar de dos digitos.

Eso asi funciona bien pero me solicita que todo eso sea UNA funcion, entonces tengo entendido que deberia juntar ambos en un mismo def pero no tengo idea como. Intente varias formas de incluir ambas pero no hay caso. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
import random

def numerosazar(n):
    random_numeros=[]
    for i in range(n):
        random_numeros.append(random.randint(1000,10000))
    return random_numeros

def sumatoria(s):
    sum(numerosazar)
    return sumatoria

azar=numerosazar(random.randint(10,100))
print("Los numeros de la lista son: ",azar, "\n")
print("===================================================" "\n")
suma=sumatoria
print("La sumataria de los numeros de la lista es: ",suma, "\n")
```

Me da este error que no se como solucionarlo:
La sumataria de los numeros de la lista es:  <function sumatoria at 0x0000013D4338B7F0>

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no deberia ser suma=sumatoria() y entre los parentesis le pasas algo?? si no, no estas llamando a la funcion...

Comment: ¿Que deberia poner entre los parentesis? Porque probe eso pero no hubo caso tampoco

Comment: `sumatoria` es una función que debe ser llamada (usando los paréntesis, de lo contrario haces referencia al objeto) en tu caso has especificado que reciba un parámetro, que nunca usas, así que le puedes pasar cualquier cosa o sacar ese parámetro

Comment: En la parte del print te referis? O dentro del def? Perdona me cuesta un monton todo esto

Comment: Entiendes lo que es llamar a una funcion? y pasarle parametros? si no, pareciera que necesitas leer sobre eso primero...

Comment: Si, los estuve repasando ultimamente. Eh intentado esto pero no hay caso 
`def numerosazar(n): 
random_numeros=[] for i in range(n): random_numeros.append(random.randint(1000,10000)) 
return random_numeros 
def azar(s): for j in numerosazar(): 
random.randint(10,100) 
return azar 

print("Los numeros de la lista son: ",azar, "\n")`

Me devuelve esto:
 **Los numeros de la lista son:  <function azar at 0x036BBC90>**

Answer (score 0):

Como te decían en los comentarios tu problema principal es que para llamar a la función debes utilizar paréntesis `azar()`, `sumatoria()`.

Otro problema es en la función `sumatoria()`.

```
def sumatoria(s):
    sum(numerosazar)
    return sumatoria
```

Le envías `s` que luego no usas, llamas nuevamente a la función de generar números. Podrias querer poner `suma = sum(lista_de_numeros)` y después devolver `suma`

No pongo el código final para darte posibilidad de acabarlo tú.

**Edito:**

En vista de que no evitamos los errores vamos a poner algo de código.

`rango = randint(10, 100)` escoge de forma aleatoria la cantidad de números, que era una de tus primeras dudas.

A la función `def sumatoria(lista_de_numeros:list):` recibe la lista de números y devuelve su suma.

```
from random import randint

def numeros_azar():
    random_numeros=[]
    rango = randint(10, 100)
    for i in range(rango):
        random_numeros.append(randint(1000, 10000))
    return random_numeros


def sumatoria(lista_de_numeros:list):
    return sum(lista_de_numeros)
```

La llamada a las funciones sería:

```
lista_numeros_azar = numeros_azar()
print("Los numeros de la lista son:\n", lista_numeros_azar, '\n' )

print("===================================================" "\n")

suman = sumatoria(lista_numeros_azar)
print("La sumataria de los numeros de la lista es: ",suman, "\n")
```

Como al crear el código debes pensar en posibles cambios, puedes crear constantes donde especificar los rangos de datos aleatorios y con una *comprensión de listas* quedaría así:

```
CANTIDAD_MIN = 10
CANTIDAD_MAX = 100

NUMERO_MIN = 1000
NUMERO_MAX = 10000

def numeros_azar():
    return [randint(NUMERO_MIN, NUMERO_MAX)
            for _ in range(randint(CANTIDAD_MIN, CANTIDAD_MAX)) ]
```

La llamada a las funciones tambien la podemos modificar:

```
lista_numeros_azar = numeros_azar()
print(f'Los numeros de la lista son:\n{lista_numeros_azar}\n{"= "*40}\n'
      f'La sumataria de los numeros de la lista es: {sumatoria(lista_numeros_azar)}\n')
```

Comment: Siguiendo lo que dices realice esto:

def sumatoria():
    suma=sum(random_numeros)
    return suma

total=sumatoria
print(total)

random_numeros es el nombre que tiene la lista vacia en el primer def, pero sigue dandome error, que estoy haciendo mal aun?

Comment: Edito la respuesta para poner códigos